# Django template tag format

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following method on a model:

```
@property
def get_total_planned_stops(self, *args, **kwargs):
    owner = self.owner
    planned_total = DailyRoute.objects.filter(stage=1).aggregate(Sum('planned_stops'))
    return planned_total
```

In my template the variable `{{ item.get_total_planned_stops}}` renders as:

```
{'planned_stops__sum': 183}
```

I only want the number to be displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) function returns a dict format data that's why you are seeing a dict in the output.

Try to access the key value.

```
 {{ item.get_total_planned_stops.planned_stops__sum }}
```